# Run table column update in batches

Tags: postgresql

I would like to run an update as below on a 100 million row table in batches so as to not cause locking/without downtime and not affecting replication.

```
Update tbl
    set col_new = col
where (do 1 day at a time)
perform pg_sleep(120);
```

col is timestamp without time_zone, col_new is timestamptz

Can someone help me with the syntax?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what part of the syntax you're having a problem with. If you're having a problem with the `do 1 day at a time` part, you'll need to provide more information about your table. If the problem is with `pg_sleep`, see [the PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html). If it's how to iterate through the dates, check the docs on [`WHILE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html).

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Comment: Thanks Lennart. This helped me https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123244/update-by-iterating-table-in-batches-faster-than-whole-table-in-postgresql